# Moving Enterprise iOS app from one MAM to another - without uninstall?

Tags: ios, mdm

We have an iOS app that was originally pushed out to users via Testflight.

Now we have our own Airwatch environment, we want to move the users over.

If a user already has the app installed via test flight, clicking the "install/Update" button in the AW app store doesn't do anything.  The users have to uninstall the testflight installed version first.  Unfortunately, this deletes the data they've created with the app.

Is there anyway around the uninstall?

Note that I've been told that both instances of the app are signed with our developer cert.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandboxing is an extremely essential piece of tech for the OS, and it is designed to specifically prevent you from reaching directly from one app into another one's data through the OS.

Every app get's it's own sandbox, and your data is stuck in it. The app has a unique identifier that is different than your developer cert. Your cert is used to sign the app, but every app you create is unique (otherwise each developer would be restricted to only having one app to their name by default)

If you really want to move the stored databases from the TestFlight installed app, you'll have to update it with the built in ability to upload their data to a remote server somewhere, then write your new App in AW to fetch that stored data and consume it.

Yes, that is probably as big of a task as it sounds, but some clever work on the server side might make the whole thing seamless and unobtrusive for the user. Just not for the developers...

Comment: Of course, if your app is only storing data locally right now anyway, you will always have user's data stuck on that device. It will always evaporate when they delete/re-install the app, and it won't transfer between devices. You may want to implement server side persistence regardless, if any of those drawbacks are counter to your desired user experience anyway.

Comment: Ryan, I understand that (at least the basics) but this is the same app.  By same I mean compiled from one source by the same people.  So wouldn't the UID be the same?  Otherwise one could never update an app right?  There's apparently something added by the MAM.

Comment: Testflight has you install their provisioning profile on test devices, so even though your cert is still involved in the signing process, the OS is going to give unique app id's to something with the Testflight profile, and something without, even if they do both share the same underlying binary.

Comment: Good proof of this point, install a version of your app using Testflight. Now install one with AW. Do you have two apps on your device or just one? the only way there can be two is if the OS thinks they are separate and distinct apps (which it does based on their unique id)

Comment: The app won't install/re-install/update via AW when the app is there from testflight.  You hit the button, but nothing happens.  No error message, nothing.

Comment: Hmm, well now I'm intrigued! I haven't pushed development apps through Airwatch, but I assumed they used the same distribution setup TestFlight does, which would create two separate apps. Perhaps the Airwatch people will understand their tech enough to suggest a workaround, but I suspect you're still going to have to push the user data from the sandbox to a remote server, then re-load it.

Comment: Talked to the Airwatch folks and their response was that their was no way to overlay the testflight pushed app with the AW pushed app...Not an unexpected answer, but I'd hoped for another.  It's still interesting that I get neither a second install of the app nor any kind of error message.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously don't understand the development ad-hoc distribution process as deeply as I thought I did! Something new to learn about on another day I guess. If you're not sure where to start on migrating your data through a server, feel free to ping me directly and I can offer my thoughts. Contact info at ryancumley dot com